# How to decode json data to array value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below jsoncode

```
{"0":{"category":"screensets","position":"top","rotate":"180","3d_file":"3d_deg_180.obj","height":"10","width":"10","x":"299","y":"166","current_roate":"0","comp_color":""},"width":"640","height":"640","name":"Test Drawing","size":"40","screen":"Conference set"}
```

How to decode in array format using jquery?

Comment: `JSON.parse()`  ?

Comment: JSON.parse(your string)

Comment: i cant get correct formate  array formate

Comment: Take a lokk to that link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: It's an object not an array

Comment: Try this - First JSON.parese(string), say d, var d = {"0":{"category":"screensets","position":"top","rotate":"180","3d_file":"3d_deg_180.obj","height":"10","width":"10","x":"299","y":"166","current_roate":"0","comp_color":""},"width":"640","height":"640","name":"Test Drawing","size":"40","screen":"Conference set"}. Then d[0] will give access inside object

Comment: Anik Islam Abhi has right it's an object, try to use [] instead to pack data you want in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Small Example** May be you help full

```js
var j ='[{"id":"1","name":"test1"},{"id":"2","name":"test2"},{"id":"3","name":"test3"},{"id":"4","name":"test4"},{"id":"5","name":"test5"}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
        console.log(k+" : "+ v);  
      $('.Record').append(k+" : "+ v+'<br>');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Record"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to turn all the contents of an object into an array, if I'm understanding correctly. This could be problematic.

Arrays in Javascript can't have named indices, so you can't have something like ['width'=>640] as you could in PHP. If that is what your looking for then you need another object to follow the following format {width:640}, much like you have right now. In other words, you need an object. Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) for more details.

My recommendation is to figure out, or at least tell us, the purpose this JSON will accomplish as it is not a simple data structure.